# Creating a static method like JOptionPane.showInputDialog() but with my own components in the dialog box

Tags: java, swing, dialog, joptionpane

How can write a method that can be used to instantiate an object through a dialog, and will not instantiate that object until input has been received?  For example, instead of
`int i = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number: ")`
how could I have something like  `char[] c = className.showPasswordDialog("Enter password: ")`             with a JPasswordField instead of a text field?

Comment: try to inherit JOptionPane to your class

Comment: @Eng.Fouad "try to inherit JOptionPane to your class"  Have *you* ever tried that?  JOptionPane is one of those highly specialized classes that, if it does not do what you want 'out of the box' (and it does, in this case), it is generally better to avoid using it  at all, and instead use a plain JDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JPasswordField pwf = new JPasswordField();
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(pwf);
char[] pswd = pwf.getPassWord();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really close to what I need, but that gives me a dialog with both a password field AND a text field.  Is there a way I can get rid of the text field?

Comment: @Morgan Barksdale. It would be nice to share how you got rid of the extra text field. I have the same problem.